# Launching eclipse product with other eclipse version

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp

Hello I have an eclipse maven product which I now want to launch on another system. I get the error below.
What does it mean and would it help to install and configure eclipse the exact same way like the one I made the product? (there the launch works obviously) [image]

The corresponding configuration settings look like this

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.6.100.v20201223-0822.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.100.v20210209-1541
```

I only need that product on a single other system, would it be "cheaper" to put some work into changing the product( maven release?) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the version of JRE was the answer here.